# control chapter starting page layout in book down

Tags: bookdown, margins

I am doing my first report using bookdown and have a question about controlling the size of the top margin on the first page of chapters. I am using the "report" type output option (documentclass:report)

I'm (very) happy with the formatting of the title and content pages; which looks like this ...

[image: contenst page layout]

But on the subsequent "chapters" - the ones generated from 01-xxx.rmd, 02-xxx.rmd etc. - I would like to reduce the top margin ...

[image: Subsequent "chapter"]

I have tried changing the top margin in preamble.tex to a negative value and while that works it affects all pages including when a "chapter" flows onto a 2 and subsequent page(s) resulting in an almost zero top margin on those pages - this is my preamble.tex file ...

[image: preamble.tex here]

I'm wondering if the `fancyhdr` library is going to be useful and included it in the index.rmd; but don't really know where to go from here ...

[image: index.rmd]

Anyone have any thoughts on this ??